# ML.NET - crashing when multithreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, ml.net

I used the ml.net model builder to make a simple image recognition program, but when I goto multi-thread it to check the images from multiple folders at the same time, it crashes. It returns "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAB191F155 (tensorflow.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000002020202."

The code is just the code that the ml.net model builder automatically generates:

```
public class ModelInput {
    [ColumnName("Label"), LoadColumn(0)]
    public string Label { get; set; }


    [ColumnName("ImageSource"), LoadColumn(1)]
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}

 public class ModelOutput {
    // ColumnName attribute is used to change the column name from
    // its default value, which is the name of the field.
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public String Prediction { get; set; }
    public float[] Score { get; set; }
}

class ConsumeModel {
    private static Lazy<PredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>> PredictionEngine = new Lazy<PredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>>(CreatePredictionEngine);

    public static string MLNetModelPath = Path.GetFullPath("MLModel.zip");

    public static ModelOutput Predict(ModelInput input) {

            ModelOutput result = PredictionEngine.Value.Predict(input);
            return result;
       
    }

    public static PredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> CreatePredictionEngine() {
        // Create new MLContext
        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        // Load model & create prediction engine
        ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(MLNetModelPath, out var modelInputSchema);
        var predEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(mlModel);
        return predEngine;
    }
}
```

the code I am using to determine the label of the image and the multi threading mechanism is a followed:

```
    public static void determine(string Dictpath) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            ModelInput sampleData = new ModelInput() {
                ImageSource = Directory.GetFiles(Dictpath)[j],
            };
            var predictionResult = ConsumeModel.Predict(sampleData);
            Console.WriteLine(predictionResult.Prediction);
        }
    }
```

And to multi-thread the application, I am using:

```
  string[] Directories = Directory.GetDirectories("Saved/");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Task.Run(() => {
                determine(Directories[i]);
            });
        }
```

I tried slowing down the amount of time it takes to start each thread, but I still get the same result. It seems to only work if it is single-threaded and crashes if its multi-threaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same [`PredictionEngine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.predictionengine-2) instance from multiple threads concurrently, without synchronization. This is only viable if the `PredictionEngine` class is thread-safe. Unless the documentation states explicitly that *"all public and protected members of the class are safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads"*, you should assume that the class is not thread-safe, and not use it this way. Otherwise you'll get undefined behavior. You can either synchronize all access to a single instance by using a `lock` or other means, or create a dedicated instance per thread.